# ¿Cómo obtener todas las fechas entre un rango de fechas en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Llevo horas pero no encuentro solución a este problema. Tengo una pequeña tabla de este tipo:

| id_habitacion | fecha_reserva | fecha_salida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-20 | 2023-07-23 |
| 1 | 2023-07-25 | 2023-07-28 |

Lo que quisiera es sacar todas las fechas que están entre `fecha_reserva` y `fecha_salida` para el registro con `id_habitacion`.

He intentado con consultas de este tipo:

```
SELECT fecha FROM ( SELECT fecha_reserva AS fecha FROM reservas WHERE
fecha_reserva >= '2023-07-01' AND fecha_reserva <= '2023-07-31'
UNION SELECT DATE_ADD(fecha_salida, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS fecha 
FROM reservas WHERE fecha_salida >= '2023-07-01' AND fecha_salida <= '2023-07-31' 
AND habitacion_id = 1 ) AS fechas_unidas ORDER BY fecha;
```

Pero no logro hacerlo, en cambio, con PHP tengo esto:

```
$fecha_reserva = '2023-07-20';
$fecha_salida = '2023-07-25';

// Convertir las fechas a objetos DateTime
$fechaReserva = new DateTime($fecha_reserva);
$fechaSalida = new DateTime($fecha_salida);

$fechaSalida->modify('+1 day');

$intervalo = new DateInterval('P1D');

$rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($fechaReserva, $intervalo, $fechaSalida);

$fechasEntreRango = array();
foreach ($rangoFechas as $fecha) {
    $fechasEntreRango[] = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
}

// Imprimir el array con las fechas
print_r($fechasEntreRango);
```

Que en teoría si saca el rango de fechas pero no me convence del todo. Tomando en cuenta que habrían bastantes registros. ¿Cómo podría resolver esto o que otra cosa puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo aquí un ejemplo de como solucionar tu problema en SQL

```
SELECT fecha
FROM (
  SELECT fecha_reserva AS fecha
  FROM reservas
  WHERE fecha_reserva >= '2023-07-01' AND fecha_reserva <= '2023-07-31' AND id_habitacion = 1
  UNION
  SELECT fecha_salida AS fecha
  FROM reservas
  WHERE fecha_salida >= '2023-07-01' AND fecha_salida <= '2023-07-31' AND id_habitacion = 1
  UNION
  SELECT DATE_ADD(fecha_reserva, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS fecha
  FROM reservas
  WHERE fecha_reserva >= '2023-07-01' AND fecha_reserva <= '2023-07-31' AND id_habitacion = 1
) AS fechas_unidas
ORDER BY fecha;
```

Comment: apenas pueda probarlo dejare por aqui los resultados gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener un resultado por cada registro basándote en esta query que he usado algunas veces. Cada resulset seria por el registro de cada habitacion.

```
WITH RECURSIVE myTable as (
    select '2023-07-01' as dt
  UNION
    SELECT DATE_ADD(myTable.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM myTable WHERE DATE_ADD(myTable.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= '2023-07-21'
)
select * FROM myTable;
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: dates]